# How to re-render the component when this.props.children has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my sample code

```
var Test = React.createClass({

componentDidMount: function(){
    //do something
}

render: function() {
    return (
        <div id="testDiv">
            <Header 
                messages={this.props.mesage} />
            {this.props.children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

I will do something in componentDidMount.
When the this.props.children, the componentDidMount will not run, why?

How can I run function when this.props.children has changed every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is run only once when components is mounted. You should use `componentWillUpdate` which is called immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received or `componentWillReceiveProps` which is invoked before a mounted component receives new props

Comment: Really appreciated. I never use componentWillUpdate, so I totally forget it.